# Giving a counterexample for the extension lemma of smooth functions

Tags: manifolds, examples-counterexamples, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

[image]

I am supposed to give a counterexample showing the conclusion is false when $A$ is not closed. I tried to find one when $M$ is Euclidean space but kept failing... Could anyone please show me a counterexample?

Comment: If $A$ is not closed there might not be continuous extension (think of $A$ as an interval minus a point)

Comment: I can think of sets but I cannot find a specific smooth function on $A$. Could you give me more hints?

Comment: If it can be extended, the left and right limit has to agree.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $f(x)=1/x$ defined on $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$, you cannot extend it at $0$

Comment: how to show that it cannot be extend to $0$